# Es legible el archivo txt en el que escribo objetos en Java (serializable)

Tags: java

Hola estoy escribiendo objetos en un archivo txt con Java y la interfaz serializable, los leo y escribo con Java sin problemas, pero cuando abro el archivo de txt me aparecen caracteres que no entiendo `w`es eso normal? Hay alguna manera de que pueda leer los datos del archivo txt desde un bloc de notas sin utilizar java?? O cuando escribo objetos en un txt solo los puedo leer con java?
Gracias, un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Al escribir los objetos los guardas como binario, por eso ves caracteres extraños. Lo que podrias hacer para ver texto plano es guardarlos en un txt con FileWriter, pero ya no seria una Base de Datos Orientada a Objetos, y te seria algo mas complicado trabajar con los objetos almacenados en ese txt.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando la respuestas de @AgustBellas siempre puedes guardas la informacion de tus objetos en texto plano pero siguiendo una estructura que te permita volver a leer o escribir la informacion de una manera simple en posteriores ocaciones un ejemplo seria que utilizaras un estructura de tipo xml o json.

Te dejo un ejemplo sobre como leer o escribir objetos en formatos en json dentro un archivo plano.

Author: Mkyong [json to file](https://mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Comment: gracias a los dos por responder, me gusto lo de almacenar datos en json, estoy mirando la libreria gson para poder pasar objetos y arraylist de objetos a json

Answer (score 0):

al serializar precisamente desinflas la información (texto) y la pasas a bits por lo tanto así lo ves en tu *.txt. Al serializar se recomienda usar archivos extensión *.ser

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que empleaste para llegar al a solución, de lo contrario esta respuesta sería un comentario, sugiero que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)